# Replace Image src before append html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a html content variable in js as

```
var htmlIs = '<p><img src="images/stories/fight_bpl.jpg" /></p>';
```

and I am appending it to the div using

```
    $("#divId").append(htmlIs);
```

but here I just want to replace the src want to add the external image link here **before append the content** so how can I do this?

Comment: Just to be clear. Is `htmlIs` really hardcoded? If so, why not modifying it directly?

Comment: no its not hardcoded its dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object:

```
$(htmlIs).find('img').attr('src', 'url').end().appendTo('#divId');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BdnYd/

For multiple images:

```
var htmlIs = '<p><img src="images/stories/img_1.jpg" /><img src="images/stories/img_2.jpg" /></p>';

var urls = ['url1', 'url2']
$(htmlIs).find('img').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('src', urls[i])
}).end().appendTo('#divId');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUFcX/

Comment: it works for me if there is one image but for multiple images its repeating same image how to use the .each or something else here can you please help me for this?

Comment: @RohanPatil Sure, can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: its hard to implement this on jsfiddle for me
just like this this 

var htmlIs = '<p><img src="images/stories/img_1.jpg" /><img src="images/stories/img_2.jpg" /></p>';

by using your answer I am getting only fist image src I want to replace all the src with links so can you know this?

Comment: thanks it works for me thanks for you contribution
hope we will meet soon with new problem :)